# Knockout.js use looped variable in foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout.js and I think it is only matter of finding the right syntax.

I want to use the looped variable of a `foreach` binding to create a component. Something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: packages">
    <li>

      <my-widget params='package'></my-widget>

      <!-- I have tried but dont' work:
      <my-widget params='this'></my-widget>
      <my-widget params='$parent'></my-widget>
      <my-widget params='$parenteContext'></my-widget>
      -->

    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there an easy way? Can `with` binding can be useful?

## EDIT:

Here is a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate it:
http://jsfiddle.net/n194o9dp/3/

I'm expecting to see a ul list with a repetition:

- a a
- b b
- c c

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n194o9dp/3/ this should works.. let me know

Comment: Sorry I started from an existing jsfiddle probably something weird happens..

Comment: Please check the right jsfiddle and tells me if it is the right one. No "nombre", no <table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `$data` which contains the current *data item* being iterated over.

More info can be founnd in the [docs for bindingContext properties](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

---

Edit: So you're getting your `params` all mixed up. Just like binding, you need to pass it `property:value` - so if you want to pass it the entire outer object you could do:

```
<my-widget params='data:$data'></my-widget>
```

That does not *need* to be called `data` it could be

```
<my-widget params='foo:$data'></my-widget>
```

The only difference would be how you access it within the widget. Also, `$data` represents a binding context, to access the actual *data* you need to use the property `data`, which gets confusing very quickly. All in all, it will work if you do it like this:

```
<my-widget params='data:$data'></my-widget>
```

And then inside the widget:

```
 ....
 viewModel: function(params) {
    this.name = params.data.name
 },
 ....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n194o9dp/5/

A better option, in my opinion is to pass what you actually need to your widget:

```
<my-widget params='name:name'></my-widget>
```

and access it directly:

```
 ....
 viewModel: function(params) {
    this.name = params.name
 },
 ....
```

Comment: ok thanks, cool I didn't know but.. `<my-widget params='$data'></my-widget>` prints undefined if I console.log it in the component constructor

Comment: Can you include some markup/code/viewmodel in your question, it will help answer the question. A minimal jsfiddle/stacksnippet example would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use component binding

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: packages, as:package}">
    <li>

    <div data-bind='component: {
        name: "my-widget",
        params: { package: package }
    }'></div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

More info about component binding is [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html).